# ios - UITableView delete button won't react to gesture

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uikit

I have a custom table view cell that has a toggle button on the left side.

When the tableview's isEditing property is set to true, the delete editing option appears properly, but when it's tapped, nothing happens.

[image]

The stranger thing is, when I tap and hold, and then drag to one side away from the button, and THEN lift, the cell finally slides over. Which isn't how it's supposed to work at all.

[image]

Even when I remove connections to the toggle button from the storyboard and the subclass, it still behaves this way.

Why is it doing this?

Comment: did you ever solve this? I'm having the exact same issue. Also, Great design! my app has almost the same little red circle in it haha

Comment: I gave up! I stopped using the delete option while in Edit mode. Only way to delete items is to leave Edit mode and swipe on the cell till the Delete button appears. So in this case, Edit mode is just for rearranging items in the list.

Comment: I Figured it out in my case, I was using a gesture recognizer in the tables' view controller. It was somehow interfering with the taps. I added this line and it fixed everything. `tapRecognizer.CancelsTouchesInView = false;`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, correct me if I'm wrong, but I think these are two different problems.

1.Nothing happens when the "delete editing" button is tapped. I would check if the "delete editing" button properly connected to the class file with an IBAction.

2.The cell slide behavior is not what is desired. I would check to see if the gesture you're recognizing is a *tap* and not a *left swipe*.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry, I should've been clearer: the round red delete button on the far left is the iOS system icon for deletion that appears when the tableView's `isEditing` option is `true`, so I'm pretty sure I can't directly control its IB connections. MY custom button is the round pink one to the right of that, which the user would tap to mark tasks as completed.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add following methods in your table view controller

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.delete) {
     //remove element from your array providing index.row
    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
     )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks – I should have mentioned I already have these methods implemented. The "DELETE" button that appears when the cell slides out of the way actually the job properly. It's just that the round red ( - ) delete button is not picking up gestures.